# How do state multiple type constraints in ShEx?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, shex

If I have data like

```
@prefix my: <http://example.com/>
my:student1 a my:Student .
my:student1 a my:FoodballPlayer .
my:teacher2 a my:Teacher .
my:teacher2 a my:BaseballPlayer .
my:teacher2 a my:RugbyPlayer .
```

and I want to say the subjects are either students or teachers and they may be zero or more of football, baseball or rugby players, how do I write that in ShEx? I know this works for one type arc:

```
my:person {
  a [my:Student my:Teacher]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything different than for one type arc constraint; just add another with your `my:*Player` value set:

```
PREFIX my: <http://example.com/>
my:person {
  a [my:Student my:Teacher];
  a [my:FootballPlayer my:BaseballPlayer my:RugbyPlayer]+
}
```

[demo](http://rawgit.com/shexSpec/shex.js/master/doc/shex-simple.html?schema=PREFIX%20my%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3E%0Amy%3Aperson%20%7B%0A%20%20a%20%5Bmy%3AStudent%20my%3ATeacher%5D%3B%0A%20%20a%20%5Bmy%3AFootballPlayer%20my%3ABaseballPlayer%20my%3ARugbyPlayer%5D%2B%0A%7D&data=PREFIX%20my%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3E%0A%0A%23%20passing%0Amy%3Astudent1%20a%20my%3AStudent%20.%0Amy%3Astudent1%20a%20my%3AFootballPlayer%20.%0Amy%3Ateacher2%20a%20my%3ATeacher%20.%0Amy%3Ateacher2%20a%20my%3ABaseballPlayer%20.%0Amy%3Ateacher2%20a%20my%3ARugbyPlayer%20.%0A%0A%23%20failing%0Amy%3Astudent3%20a%20my%3AStudent%20.%20%23%20not%20enough%20type%20arcs%0Amy%3Ateacher4%20a%20my%3ATeacher%20.%20%23%20both%20student%20and%20teacher%0Amy%3Ateacher4%20a%20my%3AStudent%20.%0Amy%3Ateacher4%20a%20my%3ARugbyPlayer%20.%0A&shape-map=%7BFOCUS%20a%20_%7D%40my%3Aperson&interface=human&regexpEngine=threaded-val-nerr)